# Two processes listen on the same port (using Jersey), but not responding to same requests

Tags: java, tcp, jersey, port, lsof

I have two very simple apps listening on TCP HTTP 4466. Both use Jersey 2.X but one is a native-image and the other is a `java UncompiledMain.java` process (I'm trying to migrate to java native images instead of JIT compilation):

```bash
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
1) java    71457 sarnobat   73u  IPv6 0x5e313f1de8147dd9      0t0  TCP *:4466 (LISTEN)
2) app     71552 sarnobat    5u  IPv6 0x5e313f1db096eb79      0t0  TCP localhost:4466 (LISTEN)
```

I'm using different runtime bindings for each (see details).

I know in more recent Linux kernel versions multiple listeners can bind to the same port but I don't know if that's related (besides, I'm using `Mac OS X` 10.15.7).

Can anyone suggest what I can do to understand why this is? Ultimately I wish to solve the problem so only one program handles all requests but I think I don't understand well enough some network basics.

### Details

Sorry the code is messy - I was hoping to get it working before cleaning it up!

#### Server 1 (via JVM) - org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory

Responds to network requests (through an ssh tunnel).

```java
JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(new URI("http://localhost:" + args[0] + "/"),
        new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class));
...
@javax.ws.rs.Path("")
public static class MyResource { // Must be public

    @GET
    @javax.ws.rs.Path("")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response list(@QueryParam("value") String iValue)
                throws JSONException, IOException {
        System.err.println("list()");
        System.out.println(iValue);

        return Response.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").type("application/json").build();
    }
```

#### Server 2 (native image) - org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer

Responds to local requests but not over network.

```java
private static final URI BASE_URI = URI.create("http://localhost:4466/");
public static final String ROOT_PATH = "";
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("\"Hello World\" Jersey Example App");

        final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, create(), true);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                server.shutdownNow();
            }
        }));
        server.start();

...
public static ResourceConfig create() {
    final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder(ROOT_PATH);

    resourceBuilder.addMethod("GET").handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, Response>() {

         @Override
         public Response apply(ContainerRequestContext data) {
             String iValue = data.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters().getFirst("value");
             System.err.println("list()");
             System.out.println(iValue);
             getMethodCalled = true;
             return Response.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").type("application/json").build();
          }
      });
```

Comment: Both servers binding to the same port, but different IP. The one binding to 127.0.0.1 gets all requests for 127.0.0.1, the one binding to 0.0.0.0 gets all but 127.0.0.1 (since there is a more specific binding). None gets IPv6 requests since no binding to IPv6 was done.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I’ll try this when I get home (I was working on it over the long weekend!)

Comment: I think that worked. Feel free to post as an answer so you get proper credit.

Comment: Side note - sun's HttpServer seems to be a bit different to the Grizzly HttpServer (I specified `localhost` in both cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both servers bind to the same port, they bind to different IP addresses. The one binding to 127.0.0.1 gets all requests for 127.0.0.1, the one binding to 0.0.0.0 gets all IPv4 traffic (but no IPv6)  except for 127.0.0.1 - since there is the other server with a more specific binding.